# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference for SharedPreferences in ActionbarActivity's Fragment

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, nullreferenceexception, android-support-library, android-actionbaractivity

My app needs to access a shared preference file in the background. Ever since I started using the v21 support library's actionbaractivity to hold my fragment, my app force closes. It force closes whenever the fragment goes off screen, but the async task is still running and trying to access that sharedpreferences file. Why is it trowing this error and how do I fix it?

Here's the stack trace:

```
12-22 23:49:49.469: E/AndroidRuntime(23016): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
12-22 23:49:49.469: E/AndroidRuntime(23016): Process: com.bernard.beaconportal.activities, PID: 23016
12-22 23:49:49.469: E/AndroidRuntime(23016): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-22 23:49:49.469: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
12-22 23:49:49.469: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
12-22 23:49:49.469: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
12-22 23:49:49.469: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
12-22 23:49:49.469: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
12-22 23:49:49.469: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-22 23:49:49.469: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-22 23:49:49.469: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
12-22 23:49:49.469: E/AndroidRuntime(23016): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
12-22 23:49:49.469: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at com.bernard.beaconportal.activities.Due_Tommorow_Fragment$Update.doInBackground(Due_Tommorow_Fragment.java:815)
12-22 23:49:49.469: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at com.bernard.beaconportal.activities.Due_Tommorow_Fragment$Update.doInBackground(Due_Tommorow_Fragment.java:1)
12-22 23:49:49.469: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
12-22 23:49:49.469: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-22 23:49:49.469: E/AndroidRuntime(23016):    ... 4 more
```

Here's the specific line of code where the error happens:

```
    SharedPreferences userName = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
            "Login_Info", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Here's the async task where the error happens:

```
public class Update extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
            SharedPreferences bDay = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
                    "Login_Info", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            String day1 = Integer.toString(bDay.getInt("Day", 0));

            String year1 = Integer.toString(bDay.getInt("Year", 0));

            String month1 = Integer.toString(1 + bDay.getInt("Month", 0));

            SharedPreferences userName = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
                    "Login_Info", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            String day = day1.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");

            String month = month1.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");

            String year = year1.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");

            String birthday = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

            System.out.println("Birthday = " + birthday);

            String user = userName.getString("username", "");

            // String user = (username).split("@")[0];

            System.out.println("Username = " + user);

            try {

                // HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                // HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                // "http://www.beaconschool.org/~markovic/lincoln.php");

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://www.beaconschool.org/~markovic/lincoln.php");

                try {
                    // Add your data
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                            2);
                    nameValuePairs
                            .add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("birthday",
                            birthday));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                }

                try {
                    Log.d("receiver", "animation stopped and downloaded file");

                    String homework = new Scanner(response.getEntity()
                            .getContent(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();

                    // String homework =
                    // Html.fromHtml(duetommorow_html).toString();

                    SharedPreferences.Editor localEditor = getActivity()
                            .getSharedPreferences("homework",
                                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "MM/dd hh:mm a");
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    String downloaded = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());

                    localEditor.putString("homework_content", homework);

                    localEditor.putString("download_date", downloaded);

                    localEditor.apply();

                    localEditor.putString("homework_content", homework);

                    localEditor.apply();

                    Log.d("receiver", "information given to shared preferences");

                    due_tommorow_list.clear();

                    parse_due_tommorow_string();

                    parse_due_tommorow_content();

                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {

                    due_tommorow_list.clear();

                    parse_due_tommorow_string();

                    parse_due_tommorow_content();

                    SharedPreferences.Editor localEditor = getActivity()
                            .getSharedPreferences("homework",
                                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

                    localEditor.putString("download_error", "yes");

                    localEditor.apply();

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                catch (NoSuchElementException e) {

                    due_tommorow_list.clear();

                    parse_due_tommorow_string();

                    parse_due_tommorow_content();

                    SharedPreferences.Editor localEditor = getActivity()
                            .getSharedPreferences("homework",
                                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

                    localEditor.putString("download_error", "yes");

                    localEditor.apply();

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                catch (RuntimeException e) {

                    due_tommorow_list.clear();

                    parse_due_tommorow_string();

                    parse_due_tommorow_content();

                    SharedPreferences.Editor localEditor = getActivity()
                            .getSharedPreferences("homework",
                                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

                    localEditor.putString("download_error", "yes");

                    localEditor.apply();

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } finally {

            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            Log.d("sender", "Broadcasting message");

            Intent intent = new Intent("up_navigation");

            intent.putExtra("message", "This is my message!");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).sendBroadcast(
                    intent);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Refresh Finished", 4000).show();

            SharedPreferences download_error = getActivity()
                    .getSharedPreferences("homework", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            String error = download_error.getString("download_error", "no");

            String download_date = "Download error, refreshed homework using homework downloaded at "
                    + download_error.getString("download_date", "");

            if (error.equals("yes")) {

                SharedPreferences.Editor localEditor = getActivity()
                        .getSharedPreferences("homework", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), download_date, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

                localEditor.putString("download_error", "no");

                localEditor.commit();

            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Create `userName` Object in `onCreate(...)` or `onCreateView(...)`

Comment: @MD your answer worked perfectly, but unfortunately I have a shared preference whose name changes after the fragment has started, and won't be able to define in onCreate. Is their anyway around not putting it in oncreate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do something time-consuming in an `AsyncTask`, when the `getActivity()` part is executed, the Activity has been destroyed. So the reference `getActivity()` return null, which is quite correct.

Which you should do is in your `Thread` or `AsyncTask`, you should always check if `getActivity()` is null, in case of the `Activity` which host your `Fragment` has been destroyed.

I don't think @I'm_With_Stupid 's answer is a good pratice, coz it's bad to hold an `Activity` reference in your `Fragment` and Fragment has already done that for you.

Comment: A co-developer had initialized a variable context = getActivity() in a fragement activity. Removing this initialization solved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

One way to get rid of this is to keep an activity reference when onAttach is called and use the activity reference wherever needed, for e.g.

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mActivity = activity;
    }
```

Now at the top of your activity put:

```
private Activity mActivity;
```

And for every SharedPreference that is giving you a problem, replace "getActivity()" with "mActivity"

Comment: note that onAttach(Activity activity) is deprecated in favor of onAttach(Context context)

Comment: it's not _the best way_, it cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you  need a Context in your code,such like this:

```
 public String getBulbsUrl(Context mcontext) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("Bublurl",0);
    String url = preferences.getString("url","http://");
    return url;
}
```